# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validation_error: Invalid Vehicle ID. Ensure the Vehicle ID matches an ID returned by the /vehicles endpoint

Tags: node.js

This Is vehicle endpoint

```
app.get('/vehicles', function(req, res, next) {
  const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
  if (!access) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  const {accessToken} = access;
  smartcar.getVehicleIds(accessToken)
    .then(function(data) {
      const vehicleIds = data.vehicles;
      const vehiclePromises = vehicleIds.map(vehicleId => {
        const vehicle = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, accessToken);
        req.session.vehicles[vehicleId] = {
          id: vehicleId,
        };
        return vehicle.info();
      });

      return Promise.all(vehiclePromises)
        .then(function(data) {
          // Add vehicle info to vehicle objects
          _.forEach(data, vehicle => {
            const {id: vehicleId} = vehicle;
            req.session.vehicles[vehicleId] = vehicle;
          });

          res.render('vehicles', {vehicles: req.session.vehicles});
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle info.';
          const action = 'fetching vehicle info';
          return redirectToError(res, message, action);
        });
    });

});
```

This request is coming smoothly with data

```
 app.post('/request', function(req, res,next) {

      const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
      if (!access) {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }

      const {vehicleId, requestType: type} = req.body;
      const vehicle = vehicles[vehicleId];
      const instance = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, access.accessToken);



        const saveRequest = async() => {
          const info = await instance.info();
          const loc = await instance.location();
          const odometer = await instance.odometer()
          const battery = await instance.battery()

          return{
            info:info,
            location:loc,
            odometer:odometer,
            battery: battery,

          }
        }
        saveRequest()
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          return res.render('dash' ,{data})

        })


       })
```

Now what i want is when checkbox is clicked it will return static text and car will be locked 
So i render the data on same hbs file as on /request and when i press the check box data will be render on same page dash.hbs with additional request its bit complicated for me and when i am trying to get to the /lock end point i am getting this error (node:15772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validation_error: Invalid Vehicle ID. Ensure the Vehicle ID matches an ID returned by the /vehicles endpoint.

```
app.post('/lock', async (req, res,next) => {

        const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
        if (!access) {
          return res.redirect('/');
        }

        const {vehicleId, requestType: type} = req.body;

        const vehicle = vehicles[vehicleId];
        const instance = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, access.accessToken);



          const saveRequest = async() => {
            const info = await instance.info();
            const loc = await instance.location();
            const odometer = await instance.odometer()
            const battery = await instance.battery()
const lock = await instance.lock()
            return{
              info:info,
              location:loc,
              odometer:odometer,
              battery: battery,

            }
          }
          saveRequest()
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data)


            return res.render('dash' ,{data})

          })


         })
```

Form submitting from here

```
<form action="/lock" method="post">


        <select class="form-control" id="vehicle" name="vehicleId">
        {{#each vehicles}}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{year}} {{make}} {{model}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>

                  <input id="bubble" name="vehicleId"  type="submit"  name="btn"/></form>
```

Comment: can you please console it req.body on your /lock route. apart from that you have same name in <select> as well as your input button, please make sure they are not conflicting.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: [Object: null prototype] { vehicleId: 'Submit' } The is what i am getting from body

Comment: As expected, now check all the vehicles your getting in your form, is id available in your selection options or not ? and remove the name from submit button or change the name

Comment: Its getting submit as value instead of id

Comment: okay, so that you're getting wrong values, now check the vehicles object from where you're calling your template (hbs), whether correct value is passed or not ?

Comment: info: {
    id: '3cd23dea-e09f-4cda-85a6-4e6c3195eed4',
    make: 'TESLA',
    model: 'Model X',
    year: 2017
  },
  location: {
    data: { latitude: 38.579769134521484, longitude: -105.8392333984375 },
    age: 2020-03-18T11:46:05.551Z
  },
  odometer: {
    data: { distance: 52268.28125 },
    age: 2020-03-18T11:46:06.559Z,
    unitSystem: 'metric'
  },
  battery: {
    data: { range: 59.82, percentRemaining: 0.57 },
    age: 2020-03-18T11:46:07.565Z,
    unitSystem: 'metric'
  }
}

Comment: i am getting this response

Comment: after removing name from submit getting empty {}
{}
{}
{}
{}

Comment: got it, id, make, model and year are inside your info object so you need use it, you can't get directly id, make, model and year. 
Note. add the name again.

Comment: <form action="/lock" method="post">
                  
            
        <select class="form-control" id="vehicle" name="vehicleId">
        {{#each vehicles}}
        <option value="{{data.info.id}}">{{data.info.year}} {{data.info.make}} {{data.info.model}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
     
                  <input id="bubble" name="vehicleId"  type="submit" /></form>  Still getting this [Object: null prototype] { vehicleId: 'Submit' }

Comment: i think problem is here  {{#each vehicles}}

Comment: Exactly the problem is there